# My code picks the value of only first item from product page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I want to get values of items like a discount, original price, discounted price, and then I retrieve the discounted price with calculation and compare with discounted price on the website I get. But the problem I face is my code only picks the values of the first item of the product page.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/nav/ul/li[1]/ul/li[6]/a"))).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
ArrayList<WebElement> a = (ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='price']/div[@class='onsale']"));

ArrayList<WebElement> b = (ArrayList<WebElement>) driver
        .findElements(By.className("was"));

ArrayList<WebElement> c = (ArrayList<WebElement>) driver
        .findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'sale-item icn']"));
List<Float> aaaa = new ArrayList<Float>();
List<Float> bbbb = new ArrayList<Float>();
List<Float> cccc = new ArrayList<Float>();
System.out.println(a.size() + " " + b.size() + " " + c.size());


for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    String[] aaa = a.get(i).getText().replaceAll(",", "").split("\\.");
    System.out.println(aaa[1] + "." + aaa[2]);
    aaaa.add(Float.parseFloat(aaa[1] + "." + aaa[2]));
    System.out.println(aaaa.get(i));

    String[] bbb = b.get(i).getText().replaceAll(",", "").split("\\.");
    System.out.println(bbb[1] + "." + bbb[2]);
    bbbb.add(Float.parseFloat(bbb[1] + "." + bbb[2]));
    System.out.println(bbbb.get(i));

    String[] ccc = c.get(i).getText().replaceAll("NEW ARRIVAL", "20").split("\\%");
    System.out.println(ccc[0]);
    cccc.add(Float.parseFloat(ccc[0]));
    System.out.println(cccc.get(i));

    float off_cal = bbbb.get(i) - (bbbb.get(i) * cccc.get(i)) / 100;
    System.out.println(off_cal);
    WebElement selitem = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
            .elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[8]/div[1]/div[2]")));
    selitem.click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    if (off_cal == aaaa.get(i)) {
        System.out.println("matched");
        WebElement addcart1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(
                By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/section[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[10]/input[2]")));
        addcart1.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("Product added to cart");
        WebElement notification_close = wait
                .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("pn-optin-disallow-btn-text")));
        notification_close.click();
```

Comment: Please provide page html source code or better url.

Comment: @pburgr : page link: https://focusclothing.pk/collections/men-gym-wear

Comment: What is the actual size of `a.size()` ? Can you see in a real run result?

Comment: @Prophet : here is output: https://prnt.sc/1aq8nha

Comment: Is it output of the entire code run?

Comment: @Prophet : yes its the entire code output

Comment: And what I asked you about?

Comment: @Prophet : you asked about the output of my code and I send you the output.

Comment: No. I asked you what is the size of `a` array

Comment: @Prophet : a array get all prices tag with items on product page. For example in my output size of array is 17 mean 17 item available on product page.

Comment: OK, no more questions

Comment: @pburgr : Can you please guide me on how I set it to click on all items and add to cart them.

Comment: Please describe step by step desired scenario.

Comment: @pburgr : Code is working perfectly only problem is it click always on the first item on the product page. What I want to do, please see steps: 1) It should click on 1st item 2) Add to cart it after matching conditions 3) Now it should go back to product page 4) On the product page, it should select 2nd item and continue the same process.

Comment: @Zaman10 I've updated the code in answer.

Comment: @pburgr : Great it's working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your code a bit:

```
package selenium;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class Zaman10 extends WebDriverBase {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        
        WebDriver driver = startChromeDriver(); // standard chromedriver setup
        
        driver.get("https://focusclothing.pk/collections/men-gym-wear");        
        dismissSubPopup();      
        
        List<WebElement> a = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='price']/div[@class='onsale']"));
        List<WebElement> b = driver.findElements(By.className("was"));
        List<WebElement> c = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'sale-item icn']"));
        
        List<Float> aaaa = new ArrayList<Float>();
        List<Float> bbbb = new ArrayList<Float>();
        List<Float> cccc = new ArrayList<Float>();
        
        System.out.println(a.size() + " " + b.size() + " " + c.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            String[] aaa = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='price']/div[@class='onsale']")).get(i).getText().replaceAll(",", "").split("\\.");
            String aa = aaa[1] + "." + aaa[2];
            System.out.println(aa);
            aaaa.add(Float.parseFloat(aa));
            System.out.println(aaaa.get(i));

            String[] bbb = driver.findElements(By.className("was")).get(i).getText().replaceAll(",", "").split("\\.");
            String bb = bbb[1] + "." + bbb[2];
            System.out.println(bb);
            bbbb.add(Float.parseFloat(bb));
            System.out.println(bbbb.get(i));

            String[] ccc = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'sale-item icn']")).get(i).getText().replaceAll("NEW ARRIVAL", "20").split("\\%");
            System.out.println(ccc[0]);
            cccc.add(Float.parseFloat(ccc[0]));
            System.out.println(cccc.get(i));

            float off_cal = bbbb.get(i) - (bbbb.get(i) * cccc.get(i)) / 100;
            System.out.println(off_cal);
            
            WebElement productLoop = driver.findElement(By.id("product-loop"));
            List<WebElement> products = productLoop.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='reveal vertical-images']"));
            products.get(i).click();
            WebElement addToCart = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"AddToCartForm\"]/div[10]/input[2]"));

            if (off_cal == aaaa.get(i)) {
                System.out.println("matched");
                addToCart.click();
                System.out.println("Product added to cart");
            }
            driver.get("https://focusclothing.pk/collections/men-gym-wear");        
            dismissSubPopup();
        }
        driver.quit();
    }
    
    public static void dismissSubPopup() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(8000);
        List<WebElement> closeButtons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/button"));
        if (closeButtons.size() > 0) {
            closeButtons.get(0).click();
        }
    }
}
```

and got this output:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 91.0.4472.101 (af52a90bf87030dd1523486a1cd3ae25c5d76c9b-refs/branch-heads/4472@{#1462}) on port 12891
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Čvc 14, 2021 9:50:31 DOP. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
17 17 17
976.50
976.5
1395.00
1395.0
30
30.0
976.5
matched
Product added to cart
836.50
836.5
1195.00
1195.0
30
30.0
836.5
matched
Product added to cart
836.50
836.5
1195.00
1195.0
30
30.0
836.5
matched
Product added to cart
1256.50
1256.5
1795.00
1795.0
30
30.0
1256.5
matched
Product added to cart
836.50
836.5
1195.00
1195.0
30
30.0
836.5
matched
Product added to cart
976.50
976.5
1395.00
1395.0
30
30.0
976.5
matched
Product added to cart
976.50
976.5
1395.00
1395.0
30
30.0
976.5
matched
Product added to cart
847.50
847.5
1695.00
1695.0
50
50.0
847.5
matched
Product added to cart
836.50
836.5
1195.00
1195.0
30
30.0
836.5
matched
Product added to cart
836.50
836.5
1195.00
1195.0
30
30.0
836.5
matched
Product added to cart
836.50
836.5
1195.00
1195.0
30
30.0
836.5
matched
Product added to cart
847.50
847.5
1695.00
1695.0
50
50.0
847.5
matched
Product added to cart
847.50
847.5
1695.00
1695.0
50
50.0
847.5
matched
Product added to cart
976.50
976.5
1395.00
1395.0
30
30.0
976.5
matched
Product added to cart
976.50
976.5
1395.00
1395.0
30
30.0
976.5
matched
Product added to cart
847.50
847.5
1695.00
1695.0
50
50.0
847.5
matched
Product added to cart
1186.50
1186.5
1695.00
1695.0
30
30.0
1186.5
matched
Product added to cart
```

Comment: Great! it's good but it always clicking on the same item and in out it shows prices of all items. Did you note that?